# TypeError: PUBNUB.init is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pubnub

I am using Node.js and I'm trying to get PubNub integrated to get my chatroom up and running. I have been following numerous tutorials and they all seem to have PubNub executing from their client-side. However, to ensure the security of my publish-key and subscribe-key I want to have PubNub execute from my server-side (Nodejs). However the problem is occurs exactly when I try to do just that. **Here is my server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var pubnub = require('pubnub');

  pubnub = pubnub.init({
  subscribe_key: 'sub-c-demo',
  publish_key: 'pub-c-demo',
  ssl: true
});
//Defining routes
var routes = require('./routes/index');

//Init express 
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Get route
app.use('/', routes);



//Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('3000 is the magic port!!');
});
```

Why do I get a `TypeError: pubnub.init is not a function` when I try to initialize pubnub?

```
$ node server
/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/project007/server.js:8
var pubnub = pubnub.init({
                    ^

TypeError: pubnub.init is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/project007/server.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3
```

I followed what seemed to be all the necessary steps:

`npm i pubnub --save`

`var pubnub = require('pubnub');`

`https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.4.2.min.js`
(Included the latest sdk in my header)

But there seems to be an error somewhere which has lead to me to be confused about the error as well as a few other things.

**1).** I have been piecing things together from all three but which of these tutorials should i really be following?

https://vimeo.com/35557579

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs/pubnub-javascript-sdk-v4

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-v4

**2).** Does my publish-key and subscribe-key need be secured or can I simply run PubNub from my client-side like shown in most tutorials?

**3).** Forget about the server-side and client, should I be executing PubNub as a javascript file and linking the script? `<script src="js/pubnubchatroom.js"></script>`

I am new to this stuff and im just trying to wrap my head around it all. Thanks in advance!

Comment: v4 sdk has new init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub V4 SDK NodeJS new Init

There is a new way to initialize your PubNub SDK.  See the following example.  v4 SDKs are not drop-in compatible.  You can mix v4 and v3 SDKs between environments successfully.

```
const PubNub = require('pubnub');
const pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey : 'demo',
    subscribeKey : 'demo'
})
```

1. Follow https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs/pubnub-javascript-sdk-v4
2. pub/sub keys can be exposed.  **never expose your secret key.**
3. PubNub is compatible with any strategy in this regard.